# Does PyGeoprocessing need to be installed?

Tags: python, raster, geoprocessing

I have not found much documentation on PyGeoprocessing, but from what I have read, I would like to try it out.  I downloaded the package from here . . . https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoprocessing.
One of the links indicates that it's a wheel file, but when I downloaded it, the source is what I got (no .whl file).

Does this utility need to be installed or do you just use the python scripts without installing it first?

I do have all of the prerequisites installed (numpy, scipy, etc.).
I don't know how many people out there are familiar with PyGeoprocessing, but I hope someone is.

Comment: I did run the setup.py script and it created a .eggs folder, but I don't know what that did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/docs/installing.rst) to install the package. Follow the link to install pip and then use the command "pip install pygeoprocessing" It will even download the prerequisites for you. But I had to do a bit of fiddling around to get the instal to work. Luckily the error messages during the install told me what was missing.

In my case I had to download first install [Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 compiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

Comment: Yes, this did it!  I didn't think it would install unless I had the whl file, but it did what you indicated.  Thanks so much!